# Is gravitational binding energy or gravitational self-energy a source of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, astrophysics, potential-energy, stars

The gravitational binding energy or self-energy of a system is the minimum energy which must be added to it in order for the system to cease being in a gravitationally bound state. Equivalently, the gravitational self-energy of a body is defined as the work done by an external agent in assembling the body from the infinitesimal elements that are initially at an infinite distance apart. A gravitationally bound system has a lower (i.e., more negative) gravitational potential energy than the sum of the energies of its parts when these are completely separated.

Is this type of energy a source for gravity? In order words, does a star have a smaller gravitational field due to its negative gravitational self-energy?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_general_relativity#The_Newtonian_limit_for_nearly_flat_space-times

Answer (score 10):

> Is gravitational binding energy or gravitational self-energy a source of gravity?

Yes. If gravitational theory satisfies the *strong equivalence principle* (SEP) then the gravitational binding energy would contribute to the gravitational field of a system in exactly the same way as other types of energy. General relativity does satisfy SEP, however there are alternative theories of gravity that violate SEP and for them gravitational binding energy would contribute differently. For such alternative theories there could be observable consequences such as (hypothetical) [Nordtvedt effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordtvedt_effect).

Observations of pulsar [PSR J0337+1715](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSR_J0337%2B1715) in a triple star system provide currently the most accurate test of SEP with results fully consistent with GR predictions.

Comment: While your answer is correct, the connection to the strong equivalence principle is not obvious.

Comment: If this was true, how would you incorporate gravitational binding energy into $T_{\mu\nu}$? E.g. for one body in a central gravity field.

Comment: Cf. https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Gravitational_stress-energy_tensor#General_theory_of_relativity_(GTR) -- *The metric in GTR depends only on the matter and the electromagnetic field in the considered reference frame.*

Comment: @JánLalinský *how would you incorporate gravitational binding energy into* $T_{μν} $? That is what the pseudotensor of gravitational field does. It allows us to recast Einstein equation in a form that has $T^{\mu\nu}+t_\text{LL} {} ^{\mu\nu}$ as a source in the 
rhs  with linear differential operator in the lhs. The inherent ambiguity in pseudotensor definition is the same ambiguity in separating energy into different ( e.g. gravitational and nongravitational) parts

Comment: @Yukterez If gravitational binding energy contributes differently to gravitational field of a system then experiments involving systems containing different fractions of gravitational energy in them would demonstrate violations of universality of free fall, this violating SEP.

Comment: I think such rewrital shows the idea that gravity energy is source of gravity is really just misinterpretation of a formal trick. It's like claiming changing electric field is source of magnetic field, because we can pronounce the term $\frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t}$ as the source term for $\nabla \times \mathbf B$, instead of really being just part of $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}$. That's fine in mathematical sense, but in physics sense, only charge and current is source of EM field.

Comment: In other words, $\partial \mathbf E/\partial t$ isn't really a  contribution to current, and $t_{LL}^{\mu\nu}$ isn't really a contribution to energy-momentum tensor.

Comment: @JánLalinský  $ t^{μν}_{LL} $
 *isn't really a contribution to energy-momentum tensor* sure, it is not contribution to *tensor* but when integrated over $t=const$ hypersurface it contributes to overall energy. Recall, that gravitational energy is not a local thing, so localizations like pseudotensors are necessarily ambiguous. But total energy of an isolated system is well defined, and gravitational binding energy (when it can be clearly separated) is  part of it (with a negative sign).

Comment: OK but if gravitational energy is not localizable, does it really make sense to say that it is source of gravity? I don't think so, despite the fact it contributes with negative value to total mass. Source of gravity is energy-momentum tensor, not total mass.

Answer (score 7):

To work out the gravitational mass of a star you would have to include the rest mass of its components, their internal energy and their gravitational potential energy. The sum of the latter two terms is negative for a bound star, so the gravitational mass of the star is lowered.

e.g. For the Sun, the virial theorem tells us that twice the internal energy plus the gravitational potential energy is zero. Thus the binding energy is about half the gravitational potential energy, roughly
$$ E_B \simeq -\frac{3GM_\odot^2}{10R_\odot}$$
and the gravitational mass is reduced approximately by a fraction
$$\frac{|E_b|}{M_\odot c^2} \simeq \frac{3GM_\odot}{10R_\odot c^2} = 3\times 10^{-6}\ , $$
but the effect is far bigger white dwarfs and neutron stars.

Comment: What is internal energy?

Comment: @Manuel e.g. the kinetic energy of particles in the gas.

Comment: Why is internal energy negative?

Comment: @Manuel it isn't.